# How many diﬀerent tables can we generate?

Tags: probability, number-theory

> We may permute the rows and the columns of the table below. How many diﬀerent tables can we generate?
>
> [image]

A hard problem. It's for discussion, thanks!

Comment: How many ways are there to permute the rows?  The columns?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think, In each column has $7!$ permutations, Now how many permutations there are in $7$ columns. This is like arranging $ 7$ sings, and each sign has $7!$ possibilities. this is what I guess

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I think that's wrong. The argument is correct for permutations of rows only or columns only separately, but e.g. if you cycle the top row to the very bottom and then the left row to the very right, you get the original matrix again.

Comment: If you move the bottom row to the top (moving all others down), then move the rightmost column to the far left (moving all the others one place to the right), it appears to me that you end up with the original matrix. So I wonder if this is so simple.

Comment: @DavidK : :-) !

Comment: @Oiue: It looks as if I overlooked an equality, indeed several.  Will rethink.

Comment: At least you have an upper-bound. That's always a start.

Comment: This is clearly connected to Latin square enumeration - worth looking at the literature. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it looks like $(7!)^2/7$, but I don't immediately see how to prove it. In any case, due to the group structure, you only need to count the number $n$ of ways of permuting rows and columns such that you get the original matrix; then the result is $(7!)^2/n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas see my solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, this is what I have tried so far:

The columns may be permuted in $7!$ ways so that the ﬁrst row is diﬀerent. The remaining rows may be permuted in $6!$ ways so that the ﬁrst column is diﬀerent. Once the ﬁrst row and the ﬁrst column have been ﬁxed, the remaining entries in the table are also ﬁxed. Hence the total number of diﬀerent tables we can generate is $7!×6!$.

Hope you like it :)

Comment: Why "the remaining rows"? Why can't the first row not be permuted?

Comment: I have a good feeling that my answer is right!